# Excel formula min and ranking combination

Tags: microsoft-excel

Which formula do I need to get first the minimum value of multiple prices and then rank it from 1 to 5. All in one formula. I’m struggling to combined the MIN and RANK excel formulas.

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have and what if there are duplicates? You may need to use SMALL, SORT & SEQUENCE functions in Excel.

Comment: You can try to provide a sample about your requirement.

Comment: How are you determining "minimum value of multiple prices"? That seems to be criteria which you would plug into `MINIFS`, possibly combining with `UNIQUE`.